# unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 1164 bytes

Tags: python, struct

I'm using struct to parse fixed width strings. However, I'm having some trouble with dealing fixed width strings larger than 1000 bytes.

For example, when I execute the following code:

```
import struct
fmt = '2s25s16s1s40s2s1s1s2s9s1s6s10s25s2s2s9s8s2s2s4x8s2x2s2s2s2s2s1x13s6s2s2s2s2s1x3s4s6s4s12x1s2s1x7s1s2s2s2s2s2s1x3s6x2s2x2s2x2s2x2s2x2s2x2s6s2x1s4x4s2s2s2s2s2s2s2s8x3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s2s2s2s2s2s2s8s2x2s2s2s2s2s150s50s4x1s2s8s15x30s30s10s15s15s10s10s10s10s12s3s3s3s3s1s3s3s1x15s2s3s8s2s2s2s2s2s16s2s3s2x2s3s2x1s1s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s10x2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s2s2s3s3s42s6s21s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s3s7s'
parse = struct.Struct(fmt).unpack_from

line = '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456'
parse(line.encode())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 6, in <module>
    parse(line.encode())
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 1164 bytes
```

I've been searching for ways to set the buffer to 1164 bytes with no success.

Comment: Your `line` is 1050 characters long. 1050 may be >1000, but it's still !=1164. So… why were you expecting this to work?

Comment: And if you just use a longer buffer, line `line*2`, your existing code successfully parses the first 1164 bytes of it.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry to bother but I still don't understand why you guys have close this question? Op has provided mcve code and he's stated clearly what problem he's found... The only reason I can see is the title being too specific to his problem instead more generic... but i don't think that's enough reason to close. Could you please elaborate a little bit? I'd like to understand the real reason as the explanation provided above doesn't match with the content I see, thanks.

Comment: @BPL The question as asked doesn’t make any sense. It’s equivalent to posting an example showing that Python says `2 < 3` and saying “I tried everything to set 2 equal to 3 (without, mind you, actually showing a single example of what you tried)”. The only way to answer such a question is telepathy, and I’m _still_ not sure what the real question was after he accepted your answer. I don’t want to just assume it was “I refuse to read the docs, so someone copy and paste them here instead”. But it’s not anything stated in the question itself.

Comment: @abarnert Mmm, not sure what you mean by telepathy here. Please take a look to [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/slm2gn6k0przq1o/chrome_2018-04-05_17-49-52.png), that's the way i see the structure of this question. IMHO you could say there is no explicit question formulated or the title is not google-friendly... but what I see here is one question where the author didn't probably understand very well what the docs were saying about an specific function. Just asking you because I'd personally like to learn how these type of questions should be edited... how would you improve it?

Comment: @BPL The organization isn't the problem. "I've been searching for ways to set the buffer to 1164 bytes with no success" is a problem—if he showed us one or more of those ways we could explain why they don't work. Showing an example that he _didn't_ have any issues with might help too, but that's pretty minor. The main problem is that it's just not clear what he doesn't get. Does he not know that `len(line) != 1164`? Or that `1050 != 1165`? If not, what could be making him think this should work? This should probably be closed as unclear rather than MCVE, but I still think it should be closed.

Comment: @BPL Again, unless the question really is "I refuse to read the docs even though I know where they are, so someone copy and paste them here instead". That would be something to downvote, not close. But I don't think that's the case here (and I don't want to assume that kind of bad faith without a compelling reason).

Comment: @BPL Put another way: What you called the "implicit question" is the part that's incomplete. A good MCVE doesn't make a good post unless it demonstrates the actual question, rather than something else. And his MCVE doesn't demonstrate… whatever it was he was means by "set the buffer to 1164 bytes", and he claims to have on that does, but hasn't shown it to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look to https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from first, it says:

> Unpack the buffer according to tthe given format. The result is a
>   tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The buffer must contain at
>   least the amount of data required by the format (len(buffer[offset:])
>   must be at least calcsize(fmt)).

Let's try first calcsize on your fmt, `print(struct.calcsize(fmt))` says 1164.

Now let's see the len of your buffer `len(line)`, it says 1050.

So the error is because you're not following the guidelines provided by the docs...

PS: `parse((line+line[0:struct.calcsize(fmt)-len(line)]).encode())`

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. For some reason I thought the buffer was a config/attribute on the struct instead of the actual line.